# CXEndCallAction throwing an Error

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I have referred many answers but I couldn't get the proper solutions. When I try to End the call using `CXEndCallAction` it shows error message as

> Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=4 "(null)"

I have checked both `CXStartCallAction` and `CXEndCallAction` having the same UUID. Can anyone explain it properly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the call appear in the list of the active calls? Error 4 seems to refer to the unknown call UUID: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxerrorcoderequesttransactionerror.code

Comment: @MikeGer I have printed the start and end call UUID which looks same.

Comment: Can it happen by any chance that you just reported the call ended once, and you get the error when you are doing it the second time? May be there is another code path or such.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue.
In my case i am calling **CXEndCallAction** two times. the first one is successful work and the second times with same **CallUUID** i show error. Please check in you code are you calling two times.

Hope this solution helps you.